# Orientation change taking time in android

Tags: android, cordova, screen-orientation, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a hybrid app using cordova. In android , at the time of changing orientation from landscape to portrait and vice-versa ,it is taking 2-3 second to adjust the view. So i am getting incomplete view of my app for 2 seconds. Is there any way to reduce this time ?
             I am using datatables to display large amount of data and getting this incomplete view .The app works fine when there is no datatable. In IOS, the app looks fine.

Comment: Things take time to process. You can store the information you get from your database in the bundle on orientation change and utilize it on orientation change, but if it really is a lot of data you may want to just use a progress bar to let people know its loading

Comment: @zgc7009 - I have already tried using progress bar . But the problem is when orientation is changing from portrait to landscape the screen is shrinking for 2 seconds ,  that's why i am getting some white space on the right side of screen & that progress bar is not coming in that white space.